# Android Maven and Refresh Problem

Tags: android, maven

i've a strange problem with maven and android

I've **3** maven project and **2** normal java maven project divided in this manner :

*normal project :*

**model project** ... packaged as jar ... contains java Pojo Bean and Interface.

**Dao Project** ... packaged as jar ... contains Db Logic - Depend on model Project

*Android Application Maven project*

**ContentProvider** ... packaged as apk ... contains ContentProviders only. Depends on Dao Project

**Editors** ... packaged as apk ... contains only Editor, Depends on Dao project

**MainApp** ... packaged as apk ... contains MyApp, Depends on DAO ...

The Problem is that if i modify DAO Project , Then do a maven clean and maven install of all apk project, then run as Android Application within Eclipse, i don't see updated app on my Emulator.

Nicely if i shut down my ubuntu workstation and restart it i can see The updated app on my Emulator.

Do you know a solution for this issue ?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, I will have to remove the app from the emulator to get the new version to deploy properly from within Eclipse.  I use the following maven command from within the project directory to remove the app. This command assumes you are using the [Android Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) with your Android app.

```
mvn android:undeploy
```

Conversely, you can also deploy the app with the following command.

```
mvn android:deploy
```